# UILabel that displays multiple sliders values

Tags: ios, iphone, uislider

I have 3 sliders and I am trying to get the overall rating label to display the **average** of the three ..they are all working and are displaying the individual slider amount in their respected labels...I am fairly new to making custom methods but how would I grab all three of the label amounts, average them and then have the overall label continuously updating as new values are being produced on the sliders?  I dont have any code to show for this at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's fairly easy: In the method that's called when any of the sliders' value changes you do the following:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    //individual values
    float val1 = slider1.value;
    float val2 = slider2.value;
    float val3 = slider3.value;

    //calculate the average
    float avg = (val1 + val2 + val3) / 3.0f;

    //display values
    label1.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%f", val1];
    label2.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%f", val2];
    label3.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%f", val3];
    labelAvg.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%f", avg];
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir thats exactly what I needed..didnt realize I had to post those in each one..! ill accept when it lets me

Comment: question though..the last labelAvg.text when I move just one slider it divides it by 3 automatically obviously..I need the overall label to represent the amount if just one slider is moved and the others arent

Comment: that's correct. it will always sum up all 3 sliders' values and divide them by 3. the average value will be correct because the values of the other (not moved) sliders stay the same.

Comment: hmm yeah i see why that should work..strange ill have to play around with some stuff..thanks

Comment: ah ok i see i had to add a simple if else statement to show that if the (val1 != 0 && val2 == 0 && val2 == 0) then just display the val1 in the overall.. glad you got me there!